# How to create mask for outer pixels when using skimage.transform.rotate

Tags: python, scikit-image

skimage rotate function create "outer" pixels, no matter how this pixels extrapolated (wrap, mirror, constant, etc) - they are fake, and can affect statistical analysis of image. How can I get mask of this pixels to ignore them in analysis?
[image: How to create such mask]

Answer (score 1):

```
mask_val = 2
rotated = skimage.transform.rotate(img, 15, resize=True, cval=mask_val, 
                                   preserve_range=False)
mask = rotated == mask_val
```

Idea: pick a value for the mask which doesn't appear in the image, then obtain mask by checking for equality with this value. Works well when image pixels are normalized floats. `rotate` above transforms image pixels to normalized floats internally thanks to `preserve_range=False` (this is default value, I specified it just to make point that without it this wouldn't work).